# Display image from database in _layout in mvc4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I am having my `_layout` as follows which works as per my requirement, but here there are couple of things I got strucked i.e I would like to display the corresponding image for that I write as follows

```
@if (Session["UserName"] != null)
{
 <div class="logged_in" id="user_navigation" runat="server">
 <a title="Your Profile" href="">
 <img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { photoId = Session["UserName"] })" height="50" width="50" class="photo" />
</a>
</div>
}
```

But this is not showing image as per required for me so can some one help me I would like to display the image from the database after user logged in also I would like to display the `session` values in some control too

This is my controller code

```
public ActionResult GetPhoto(string photoId)
        {
            byte[] photo = null;
            var v = db.tblUsers.Where(p => p.UserName == photoId).Select(img => img.Photo).FirstOrDefault();
            photo = v;
            return File(photo, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

Comment: `But this didn't worked for me` - What didn't work? What happened? Did you get an error? Could you describe the problem you are encountering in details? Is the `GetPhoto` action being invoked? Why are you passing the currently authenticated username as query string parameter - that's a huge security vulnerability?

Comment: Unable to display image as per written

Comment: Alright, questions: is the controller action being invoked? what do you have inside `Session["UserName"]`? What do you see in the generated HTML? Is there an `img` tag? What is its `src` pointing to?

Comment: inside `Session["UserName"]` I can see my value as per needed generated html when view source is as follows `<img src="UserController/GetPhoto/<%= Html.Encode(Session["UserName"]) %>' alt=""" />`

Comment: Got it `<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto","User", new { photoId = Session["UserName"].ToString() })"                    
                    height="50" width="50" class="photo" />` this works for me

Comment: Thanks for your `generated HTML` tip other wise I couldn't make it :)

Comment: I have posted an answer which covers this as well as the security vulnerability you need to fix in your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with the `<img>` syntax. It should be like this:

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto","User", new { photoId = Session["UserName"].ToString() })" height="50" width="50" class="photo" />
```

According to the comments section you seem to have used the WebForms view engine in your actual code (`<%= Html.Encode(Session["UserName"]) %>`).

This being said you have a far more serious issue with this code. The currently authenticated user should never be passed as parameter. That's a huge security vulnerability. So start by getting rid of it:

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "User")" height="50" width="50" class="photo" />
```

and then inside your controller action you could retrieve it:

```
public ActionResult GetPhoto()
{
    string user = Session["UserName"] as string;
    byte[] photo = db
        .tblUsers
        .Where(p => p.UserName == user)
        .Select(img => img.Photo)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return File(photo, "image/jpeg");
}
```