# How to Display Image Produced from byte in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and I'm stuck with a problem I need to display an image which is stored in database as byte in my MVC 4 application  I know how to produce the image from the byte but I dont know how to display it in the App. how can I solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the image directly from the db, you need a controller that delivers the image and call that controller in the view. This posts shows how to do it:

[Display image from database in _layout in mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686237/display-image-from-database-in-layout-in-mvc4)

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you have the FileData as a `byte[]` and the mime type as a `string`, then try this controller method:

```
    public FileContentResult Get(Guid fileId)
    {
        var file = _fileService.GetFile(fileId);
        if (file != null)
        {
            return File(file.FileData, file.MimeType); 
        }
        else
        {
            // Return 1x1px transparent png (67 bytes) - This is a clever trick of mine to serve an empty image without reading it from the disk. You may not want to do this!
            return File(Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), "image/png");
        }
    }
```

Then in your view you need the URL to the image, which is obtained by doing this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Get", new {fileId = item.ID})" />
```